# MySQL treats two different strings same

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL throws an error on INSERT QUERY when two different strings **jardiniere** and **jardinière** are inserted in a column (named `word`) having UNIQUE KEY enabled.

> **Error:** #1062 - Duplicate entry 'jardinière' for key 'word'

I've also included following line before INSERT Query (in PHP File)

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What's the collation and charset on the table/columns?

Comment: @Qirel you just beat me to it.

Comment: Only utf8_bin collation would consider them to be different as they are semantically the same word.

Comment: @Qirel Collation `latin1_swedish_ci`

Comment: @AlexK. Sort of beat me to the point, but you would need it to be `utf8_bin` instead of `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collation of the table (the specific column) needs to be set to `utf8_bin` in order to separate the two characters from one another.

Run the following query to update the charset and the collation (you can set it to `utf8_bin` if you need it on just that column).

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Keep in mind that unlike `latin_*` and `utf8_XXX_ci`, the `utf8_bin` is *case sensitive* when comparing.